# Running pdb in daemon mode with WSGI

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

I am running a Python script on Apache 2.2 with mod wsgi.

Is it possible to run pdb.set_trace() in a python script using daemon mode in wsgi?

**Edit**
The reason I want to use daemon mode instead of embedded mode is to have the capability to reload code without having to restart the Apache server every time (which embedded mode requires). I would like to be able to use code reloading without restarting Apache everytime and still be able to use pdb...

Comment: I suggest you deploy using FCGI or similar where you can manually control the Python process and run it as foreground, set pdb, but still have it connected to Apache. It's known to work, unlike with WSGI where you cannot attach terminal for the process.

Comment: Couldn't you make the pdb stuff global and use a secret URL / key to enable/disable it? You've got a programming language with reflection and the ability to inject arbitrary code any time you want. Should be zero cost when disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need to be able to use the amazingly powerful `pdb`, dropping a `pdb.set_trace()` wherever I wanted to debug some part of the Python server code.

Yes, **Apache** spawns the **WSGI** application in a place where it is out of your control [1]. But I found a good compromise is to

1. maintain your Apache `WSGIScriptAlias`
2. and also give yourself the option of starting your Python server in a terminal as well (testing locally and not through **Apache** anymore in this case)

So if one uses `WSGIScriptAlias` somewhat like this... 
    pointing to your python WSGI script called `webserver.py`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName myawesomeserver
    DocumentRoot /opt/local/apache2/htdocs

    <Directory /opt/local/apache2/htdocs>
        [...]
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /opt/local/apache2/my_wsgi_scripts/webserver.py/

    <Directory /opt/local/apache2/my_wsgi_scripts/>
        [...]
    </Directory>

    [...]
    SSLEngine on
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

And so your `webserver.py` can have a simple **switch** to go between being used by Apache and getting started up for debugging manually.

Keep a flag in your config file such as, in some `settings.py`:

```
WEBPY_WSGI_IS_ON = True
```

And `webserver.py` :

```
import web
import settings

urls = (
    '/', 'excellentWebClass',
    '/store', 'evenClassier',)

if settings.WEBPY_WSGI_IS_ON is True:
    # MODE #1: Non-interactive web.py ; using WSGI
    #   So whenever true, the Web.py application here will talk wsgi.
    application = web.application(urls, globals()).wsgifunc()

class excellentWebClass:
    def GET(self, name):

        # Drop a pdb  wherever you want only if running manually from terminal.
        pdb.set_trace()

        try:
            f = open (name)
            return f.read()
        except IOError:
            print 'Error: No such file %s' % name

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # MODE #2: Interactive web.py , for debugging.
    #   Here you call it directly.  
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

So when you want to test out your webserver interactively, you just run it from a terminal,

```
$ python webserver.py 8080
starting web...
http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

*[1] Footnote: There are some really complex ways of getting Apache child processes under your control, but I think the above is much simpler if you just want to debug your Python server code. And if there are actually easy ways, then I would love to learn about those too.*